# Проблема с ./configure

Tags: linux

У меня есть matlab2k9b.tar.gz. Я его распаковал. Как и посоветовали в инете, пытаюсь выполнить

```
./configure
```

мне в ответ:

> `bash: ./configure: Нет такого файла или каталога`

Дальше инсталлить или мэйкать нет смысла. Прочитал файл readme, там пишут:

> `"3.1 Installation Commands On UNIX systems:  install"`

Хорошо, нажимаю инсталл

> `"install: пропущен операнд, задающий файл"`

Ну и почему в readme многоуважающими прогерами не указано, какой файл надо обработать? Привожу содержимое папки, куда распаковал содержимое matlab2k9b.tar.gz.

```
activate.ini          inst_doc.pdf        mac_install_guide.pdf  update
install               license.txt         matlab2k9b.tar.gz      utils
InstallForMacOSX.app  lic_server.dat      matlab.png
install.txt           lic_standalone.dat  readme.txt
```

Ну, и как мне инсталлировать или хотя бы собрать deb-пакет в линуксе? Расскажите, как пошагово все это выполнить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

М-м-м-м... Вообще Вы все делаете не так.
Во-первых, читаете README или readme.txt. Внимательно и вдумчиво. Далее возможно поможет install.txt
Во-вторых, смотрите - есть команда install (общесистемная) и скрипт, который лежит в каталоге MathCAD'а. Если Вы в консоли набираете

```
-> install
```

то вызывается общесистемная команда. Вам же нужен `./install` (из текущего каталога), ну, или `sh ./install` (если это скрипт)

В третьих, deb-пакет зачем? Тем более, что у разных дистрибутивов свои форматы бинарных пакетов (deb, rpm и пр). И зависимости тоже неясно кто прописывать будет.

А это:

> ак и посоветовали в инете, пытаюсь выполнить ./configure

нужно в том случае, если программа собирается из исходных кодов и есть скрипт configure в корневой папке программы.

Еще очень полезно проверить права доступа к файлам. Напоминаю, что eXecute (исполнение) - это отдельное право.

Comment: Поскольку в списке файлов есть install.txt, то инструкция по установке скорее всего там. Но это, вероятно написано в readme.txt. Файл с названием "прочти меня" туда положили для того, чтобы его прочитали. Ну и для удаления без проблем в будующем возможно использовать утилиту checkinstall. Правда гарантий, что всё будет нормально никто не даст.

Answer (score 0):

Фича с sh прошла. Без нее консоль ругается, что такой команды нет. Собирать деб нужно было, чтоб инсталлировать нормально, ибо потом без нее прога намусорит в компе, если надо снести её.

Comment: А checkinstall не спасёт отца Русской демократии?

Comment: с такой командой не работал. в моем случае надо было инсталлировать бинарники